# FirebasePerformance: Method traces ( using @AddTrace) don't show up in Logcat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I updated my AndroidManifest to show the performance metrics on logcat

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_performance_logcat_enabled"
    android:value="true" />
```

It seems to work for Custom Trace. But, method level traces using @AddTrace are not showing up in logcat. Is this expected or am I missing something?

Comment: If the SDK isn't working the way you expect, tou should file a bug report with Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature

Comment: have you found any solutions?